# Applescript Alarm Clock

Tags: applescript

I am new to coding and figured I would start with applescript.  I have managed to create an app via applescript that will open a page, I've even managed to link this to calendar to have it run at a specific time and date so that it will act as an alarm clock.  What is beyond my skill set is to get a particular part of the webpage that opens to activate.  Here is the current code, which will open NPR's front page.

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "http://www.npr.org"
end tell

What I would like to further do is be able to open the hourly news stream when the app runs so I can have the NPR news stream kick off to wake me up in the AM from my Mac.

Thanks for any help.
-J

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript in Safari to access the web page stuff. You can google many tutorials on javascript. Here's an example...

```
set theURL to "http://www.npr.org/"

tell application "Safari"
    tell document 1
        if URL is not theURL then
            open location theURL
            delay 5
        end if
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('jquery_jplayer_1').click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Regulus,Thanks for the help.  I see how the getElementById works and what it plays.  The stream I am looking for involves clicking on the class "in-caret" ('Listen' on the screen) which toggles a drop down box to reveal the latest news / npr newscast.  The play button has the class "icn-media" nested under the class "latest-news-link".  I've tried modifying the Javascript line to "do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('latest-news-link').click();"" and any other classes in the vicinity but no luck.  What am I missing?